# Getting a formula validation error, can anybody spot where I am off?

Tags: formula, error, compile-error

```
IF (
    AND (
        ts2__Job__c.Days_Search_Open__c >= 0, 
        ts2__Job__c.Days_Search_Open__c <= 4
    ), 
    "0 - 4",
    IF (
        AND (
            ts2__Job__c.Days_Search_Open__c >= 5, 
            ts2__Job__c.Days_Search_Open__c <= 8 
        ),
        "5 - 8",
        IF (
            AND (
                ts2__Job__c.Days_Search_Open__c >= 9, 
                ts2__Job__c.Days_Search_Open__c <= 18
            ),
            "9 - 18",
            IF (
                AND (
                    ts2__Job__c.Days_Search_Open__c >= 19, 
                    ts2__Job__c.Days_Search_Open__c <= 30
                ), 
                "19 - 30",
                IF (
                    AND (
                        ts2__Job__c.Days_Search_Open__c >= 31, 
                        ts2__Job__c.Days_Search_Open__c <= 60
                    ),
                    "31 - 60",
                    IF (
                        AND ( 
                            ts2__Job__c.Days_Search_Open__c >= 61,
                            ts2__Job__c.Days_Search_Open__c <= 90
                        ),
                        "61 - 90",
                        IF (
                            ts2__Job__c.Days_Search_Open__c >= 91,
                            "91+",
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I am attempting to group ranges of days and getting this error:

> Warning
>
> Error when encoding row-level formula: Syntax error. Found ')'

Comment: Upvote just for your editing. Thanks for indenting it out, helps a ton with questions of this nature.

Answer (score 7):

Your last `IF` block has no `value_if_false`.

**What you have**

```
IF (
    ts2__Job__c.Days_Search_Open__c >= 91,
    "91+",
)
```

**What you need**

```
IF (
    ts2__Job__c.Days_Search_Open__c >= 91,
    "91+",
    "SOME OTHER VALUE (Missing)"
)
```

---

Please note that your formula can be simplified a bit by defining only the top end of each range, if you are willing to add a `<0` bucket.

```
IF(My_Field_Path__c < 0, "<0",
    IF(My_Field_Path__c < 5, "0-4",
        IF(My_Field_Path__c < 9, "5-8",
            IF(My_Field_Path__c < 19, "9-18",
                IF(My_Field_Path__c < 31, "19-30",
                    IF(My_Field_Path__c < 61, "31-60",
                        IF(My_Field_Path__c < 91, "61-90", "91+")
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```